# How to autostop jmeter once all URL execute from Excel sheet

Tags: jmeter

I have 250+ URL in excel sheet and i need to run all 250+ URL and once 250+ URL execute jmeter should auto stop.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [CSV data set config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) change **Recycle on EOF** to `False` and **Stop thread on EOF** to `True`. This will make Jmeter stop when the CSV file reach the end of file.

Check [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) for more info.

Comment: Hi i used virtual user as 30 and thread group run for 30 virtual users. How can i cross verify that the 250+ URL are hitted and getting the result.

Comment: Add view result tree listener at the same level of your thread group and check the requests that has been sent and their response.

Comment: hi are you telling about above the screen shot value

Comment: No, i meant [View result tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

Comment: there i get 30 response and how i can verify whether the 250+ hitted by user or not

Comment: If you want the 30 Vusers to keep running till the 250+ URL are hit, then tick the **Forever** box on the thread group.